# How do you read "$a_n$" in English?

Tags: translation-request, pronunciation

What is the correct way to read "$a_n$" in English? What is the translation of what in Spanish is "$a$ sub $n$"?

Comment: My friend Rik tells the story of the time his aunt was visiting from Germany and asked him “Rik, what is the word, in English, for when you are happy because someone else is sad?”

Comment: When there is no possible confusion with $a^{(n)}$, I often just say a n.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've always read it as "a sub n."

Answer (score 11):

Believe it or not, the usual way is ‘$a$ sub $n$’.

Comment: That's funny. Thanks!

Comment: @user88299: You’re welcome!